# Django Reportlab using HTML

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, reportlab

Hello guys I'm trying to make a little PDF with python django using the reportlab library I've made some pdf with just some text but I have no idea how to do it with html, I wonder if you guys can give me an example using something like `<h1>Hello</h1>` or something with html, because if I use drawString it show me `'<h1>HELLO</h1>"`

Let me show you my source.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
import os
from io import BytesIO
import PIL.Image

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hola Marcos :D')


def reporte(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="informe.pdf"'


    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    buffer = BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=letter)

    logo = ImageReader('http://django-unfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/img/python-logo-256.png')

    numero =150
    uno = 204 - numero
    dos = uno

    p.drawImage(logo, 250, 500,uno,dos, mask='auto')

    p.setLineWidth(.1)
    p.setFont('Helvetica',22)
    p.drawString(30,750,'Company')

    p.setFont('Helvetica',22)
    p.drawString(30,725,'Report')

    p.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 12)
    p.drawString(480,759,"7/01/1986")
    p.line(460,747,560,747)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    suma = (7*75675678567856785)*70+2*9090
    suma = str(suma)
    resta = 100-9
    resta = str(resta)

    p.drawString(100, 630, 'Este podria ser el primer informe de empresa con python Django')
    p.drawString(100, 600, suma)
    p.drawString(100, 590, resta)
    p.drawString(100, 570, 'O2A5X1996A3B4B4A6')


    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(pdf)
    return response

# Create your views here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but you can create PDF via HTML, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wkhtmltopdf